# How to configure multipart in Grails?

Tags: grails, multipart

I'm using Servlet 3.0 and the [Spring Security REST plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) in my Grails application. When I run the application in Glassfish and when the security plugin looks for the access token in a request, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request.getParts is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.checkMultipartConfiguration(Request.java:4533)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:4539)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1086)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:60)
at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty$getProperty.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.ServletsGrailsPluginSupport$_enhanceServletApi_closure1.doCall(ServletsGrailsPluginSupport.groovy:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:81)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1161)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:33)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:293)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader.findToken(BearerTokenReader.groovy:47)
```

Where do I have to place the multipart configuration?

I'm not uploading a file, so I guess I can't use the annotation. But there's also no web.xml in Grails.

I'm using Grails 2.5.0 and GlassFish 4.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the log of the request that is causing this error

Comment: I doubt that the request log would help. For short, in this case it's a HTTP POST request with some form data, but the exception is thrown for other requests, too. I know why the exception is thrown, but I don't know where to place the multipart configuration. Maybe I have to add something to Config.groovy, but I didn't find any documentation about that. I found yesterday that it's possible to generate a web.xml template, but is this the intended way of configuration?